# How to move file onto my media player, without a drive letter

Tags: python, media-player

I want to move a file onto my media player with python, but it does not have a file location. (the path is This PC\Q5\Device storage\Movies).

If I try shutil.move(source, This PC/Q5/Device storage/Movies/Unorganized) I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in 
move()
File "C:\Users\simon\Downloads\YT Download\YTDownloadNowPlsIdkForTimkoo.py", line 20, in move
shutil.move(source, destination)
File "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 825, in move
copy_function(src, real_dst)
File "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
File "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'This PC/Q5/Device storage/Movies/Unorganized'

Comment: please specify what you mean "it does not have a file location"...  these must be a [1] source and [2] destination path.